# How do I fully specify settings for an image to be used as a GaugeMarker?

Tags: image, gui-construction

I have designed a ClockGauge and wish to use three different images for the hour, minute and second hands.The images are not rectangular and are not symmetrical. The code used is below:

```
'ClockGauge[ AbsoluteTime[], ImageSize -> Large, 
 GaugeLabels -> {Placed["DateShort", Top], "Value"}, 
 GaugeMarkers -> {minuteHand, secondHand, hourHand}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Mallacoota", Large, Bold] ]'
```

The output is:
[image]

I want to specify that, for example, the seahorse rotates about the tip of its tail and the tip of its snout indicates the time. How should I modify the command.

The images are imported from the hard drive.

Thanks for helping.

The images used as clock hands are below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A lot depends on the images you're using. Please [edit] your question to add a copy of each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Rotate slightly and crop the image so that the tip of the tail is at the bottom-left corner and the tip of the snout is at the bottom-right corner of the bounding rectangle. (2) `ImagePad` to have the image on the upper part of the rectangle:

```
seahorse = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRwYn.png"];
seahorse2 = RemoveBackground @ ImageCrop @ Rasterize @ Rotate[seahorse, 2 Degree];

hand = ImagePad[seahorse2, {{-5, 40}, {ImageDimensions[seahorse2][[2]], 0}}];

Dynamic @ Refresh[ClockGauge[Round @ AbsoluteTime[], ImageSize -> 500, 
   GaugeLabels -> {Placed["DateShort", Top], "Value"}, 
   GaugeMarkers -> {None, None, hand}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Mallacoota", Large, Bold]], 
  UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Why did you add 40 pixels to the length of the image?

Also, some of the standard clock hands are centred about a point within the image. How do I specify that the image rotates about a specific pixel coordinate?

Comment: @JohnBaratta, added 40 pixels on the right to make the snout point to the ticks (try changing 40 to 0 to see what we get without the padding on the right). Re changing the point to rotate around, it should be possible but can't think of a quick way otomh.